# Show row selected in UIPickerView in another View

Tags: uipickerview

i have two view controlled by a UITabBarController, and in one there is a UIPickerView, i wanna know how i can see the string row selected in another view when i start the application, beacuse the view with the UIPickerView is a setting View and i need the string selected in the other view...how i can do it?...

Answer (score 0):

if each view has an own view controller you have to pass the selected row to the other view controller class with a notification or a delegate.

Comment: could you explain how to notify another view controller from the datasource pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: for example and pass the string?

Answer (score 0):

when you select the picker value delegate method call

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

in this method you get string and then you push/add new view and pass this value to new view using property 
if you have any question feel free to ask.
thanks